# Angular Multi-Monitor App

Tags: angular

We received requirements on the UI portion of the next generation application for our line of business.

Our users are used to a desktop application on the legacy app.  For the future we want to put it into a web app for all the benefits normally attributed to that kind of change.

One of the requirements are to have panels that can pop-out for multi-monitor support.

I am looking for specific examples and references if this has been done with an Angular app.  Some brief skimming of the internet did not turn up anything.

These popped out panels would contain web components related to the main view. When a record is changed in the main view, the supporting components change.  The detached components also need to update the main panel.

I have seen a couple references to web sockets, but nothing concrete.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this question that it warranted down voting?

Comment: https://github.com/golden-layout/golden-layout - try this. We have built our solution using this amazing library

Answer (score 0):

I guess no. 
I think you would like to open Angular-Components in a new Window, having it open on your 2nd Display and maybe press a save button to close it and continue working on your main App or even have the 2nd Window open for several time while working with both windows. As soon as you open a new windows you are out of your Angular scope, you could of course parse JS stuff between the windows but you won't be able to access Angular stuff from outside your initial app-window.

If you only wish to change data in a Backend, you could do this with Javascript and the data in your mainapp would of course be updated, even though this is not the good practice way to do so as Angular is a framwork designed for Single Page Applications.